# ReferenceError: describe is not defined (decision engine build)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am building a decision engine that depends on javascript modules and libraries but everytime i run node index.js it shows the below error. I don't understand the how the error came about[image]
And below is how my package.json looks

```
{
  "name": "mocha",
  "version": "3.5.3",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "orderSystem/node_modules/mocha/lib"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I dont understand how the describe is not defined where else it is in the .js file, below is how it looks where it shows the error[image]
Your assistance will be highly appreciated, thank you

I tried restarting the build and it showed the same error again. I thought i had done something wrong there. I was expecting it to show results because i am testing the example it came with.

Comment: Try replacing this `"test": "orderSystem/node_modules/mocha/lib"` with this `"test": "mocha"`

Comment: I did and it returned the same error